# Nested JSON in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

First off, I would like to ask for your patience since this question is going to be really noobish. I've tried researching to no avail, as I can't put everything into place.

Anyway, **I need to be able to render items in the database I will create as JSON.** However, it is nested and I am unsure how would I go about creating the model for it:

```
{
"name": "name",
"description": "description",
"review": [
    {
        "rating": "rating",
        "content": "content"
    },
    {
        "rating": "rating",
        "content": "content"
    }
]
}
```

**Creating the Database**

Do I create two tables first (i.e. Item and Review), like so?

```
rails g model Item name:string description:string review:string
rails g model Review rating:string content:string
```

I've read that I need the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` method, but again, I am unsure how to use it.

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :reviews
end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
end
```

**Populating the Database**

If by some chance the above is correct, how do I actually populate the database using the console or *seed.rb*?

**Rendering as JSON**

This is what I have for non-nested entries:

```
def index
   @items = Items.all
   render :json => @items.as_json(:except => [:id, :created_at, :updated_at])
end
```

As you can tell, I am confused and lost. I would very much appreciate any input. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're almost there, and are definitely on the right track.

When you create your models, you won't need `review:string` for Item, but you will need a `item_id` for Review (to hold the associated Item.id), like such:

```
rails g create Item name:string description:string
rails g create Review rating:string content:string item_id:integer
```

The way rails associations work is it will store the `item.id` for the associated `Item` record in `review.item_id`.  It will do this automagically, so all you need to do is use them.

To create the association between Review and Item:

```
new_review = Review.create(rating: 'great', content: 'Wonderfully done')
new_item = Item.create(name: 'My Item', description: 'My Item description')
new_item.reviews << new_review
```

To access the associated review(s) from Item:

```
new_item.reviews.each do |review|
    review.rating
    review.content
end
```

Because it's a `has_many` relationship, an instance of `Item` will have a `reviews` method which returns an array of `Review` objects that have an `item_id` matching the current `Item.id`.

Likewise, an instance of `Review` will have a `item` method (note the singular use here), which just returns the single associated `Item` record object.

Make sense?

Additionally, when you output a record with an association in JSON (as you've done in your example), it should create output close to what your example shows.

Render your JSON as follows:

```
@items = Item.all
render :json => @items.to_json(:include => [:reviews], :except => [:id, :created_at, :updated_at])
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I got stuck at storing the newly-made review, unfortunately. It tells me it cannot find the method--`undefined method 'reviews'`.

Comment: have you migrated your database?: `rake db:migrate`

Comment: Make sure you've created the associations like in your example and applied the database migration with `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: @benjaminjosephw Yes, I have.

Comment: `Item.reviews << new_review` is incorrect. You need to associate data with an instance of `Item`, not on the `Item` class itself.

Comment: It now accepts it without error, thank you. Rendering, however, only shows `"name"` and `"description"`. Is `:include` applicable here?